# To vocode or to convolve, that be the question....

Tags: vocoder, vocoding, convolution

When do you find yourself using each? What kind of sources are you using in the examples you're giving? Any cool setups that work for you?

Edit: Not reverb. I don't care if you mention that you use a convo verb plugin and use different convolutions, but just not "room" simulation for this thread. Go!

Comment: I've built some really fun convolving delays and such like in Max/MSP.  But I actually don't use it in a specific application all that often.  Convolution/vocoding tends to be my funTime playToy.  I can imagine however, that a LOT of people use it for creature voices and craft/car fly/driveby's.

I would also hazard a guess and say that most people are going to reply "Reverb!" to which I would heartily agree.

Comment: Yea, I should actually say I am NOT REFERRING TO CONVO REVERB. I am aware of that's usage, and the plug in that you use may be ea convo verb like space designer just used in an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

Just me, but I tend to go to vocoders when I want a Dialog Effect (like something special for a mechanical character). I think it's a leftover from the days of the original Battlestar Galactica and the vocoded Cylon voices which I thought were AWESOME as a youngster.

Convo I tend to use for SFX more, and specifically interesting ambiences. On one animated show I work on, the characters go to a different planet each week - circus planet, pirate planet, fix it planet etc.. The ambience of the planet is a base ambience plus an ambience that I usually make by taking something appropriate to the planet (say a construction site for the fix-it planet) and then passing it through TLSpace with some interesting impulses, ranging from wind, to synth drones. I also like to pass a sustained sound through convo with a rhythmic sound to get interesting rhythmic sounds when needed.

Comment: Any clips? Love to hear some of those. 